# Equivalente de java en python

Tags: java, python

Me gustaría implementar un **switch-case** de java en mi código Python para no tener que usar tantos **if**, hay algún método parecido o que realice la misma función?

Lo necesito porque quiero realizar varias condiciones a una variable, por ejemplo:

```
if x = 0:
 do z
if x = 1:
 do y
if x = 2:
 do n
```

Lo que más me interesa es optimizar el código para no tener 50 líneas de ifs o parecido.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En python no existe nada como el `swith..case` de *Java/C*. La opción es encadenar sentencias `if..else`, más en concreto, `if..elif`:

```py
if x = 0:
 do z
elif x = 1:
 do y
elif x = 2:
 do n
```

Si está claro que la decisión depende del valor de una variable, a veces se usa una lista de funciones, que en python son objetos igual que los demás:

```py
def do_z():
  do z

def do_y():
  do y

def do_n():
  do n

# simulación de un switch..case
[ do_z, do_y, do_n][x]()
```

Evidentemente, no se está contemplando que la variable `x` pueda salirse del rango de opciones. Un método más seguro sería usar un diccionario de esta forma:

```py
def do_z():
  do z

def do_y():
  do y

def do_n():
  do n

def default():
  do default

# simulación de un switch..case
cases = {1: do_z,
         2: do_y,
         3: do_n}

do_case = cases.get(x, default)
do_case()
```

Si `x` no está en el diccionario `cases`, entonces `cases.get()` devuelve la función `default`, que funcionaría como la cláusula `default` de un `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

El primer paso es declarar un diccionario con los valores de tu X en la parte de las claves, por ejemplo:

```
diccionario = {
        0: funcX0,
        1: funcX1,
        2: funcX2,
        3: funcX3,
    }
```

Luego, llamamos a la función get sobre el diccionario:

```
res = diccinario.get(a,
'''Esta parte sólo se mostrará en el caso de que no exista el valor a dentro de la función'''
'Default valor');
```

Por último, mostramos por pantalla res, que habrá llamado a nuestra función en función del valor de x:

```
print(res)
```

Para más información, de dejo un [enlace](https://www.clubdetecnologia.net/blog/2017/python-como-se-implementa-una-sentencia-switch-case/) a una página que explica muy bien cómo replicar los switch de Java en Python.